# Handling strings with identical values?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-10.3-rio, ansistring

I am using Delphi 10.3 to extend some working code. I am having a problem with strings.

I'm filling a record. Only the first 2 fields, name and org_name, are giving me problems. When name and org_name have values different from each other there is no problem. But when name and org_name have identical values, name is read correctly but org_name yields only the first character of its string.

```
  TMYSQL_FIELD51 = record
    name:             PAnsiChar;   // Name of column
    org_name:         PAnsiChar;   // Original column name, if an alias
  ...
  end;
```

The values are retrieved from a JSON object and written to the record:

```
fFieldInfo: TMYSQL_FIELD51;
lInput: TJSONValue;
FieldOffsets: TMYSQL_FIELDOFFSETS; //a record containing offsets into TMYSQL_FIELD51

PPAnsiChar(NativeInt(@fFieldInfo) + FieldOffsets.name)^ := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(lInput.GetValue<String>('label'))); 
PPAnsiChar(NativeInt(@fFieldInfo) + FieldOffsets.org_name)^ := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(lInput.GetValue<String>('name')));
```

Note: filling the fields in a more usual way does not change the outcome:

```
fFieldInfo.name := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(lInput.GetValue<String>('label')));
fFieldInfo.org_name := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(lInput.GetValue<String>('name')));
```

Later, name and org_name are extracted like this:

```
PMYSQL_FIELD51 = ^TMYSQL_FIELD51;
MYSQL_FIELD: PMYSQL_FIELD51;
FieldOffsets: TMYSQL_FIELDOFFSETS; //a record containing offsets into TMYSQL_FIELD51

Result.ColumnLabel := ValueToString(PPAnsichar(NativeUInt(MYSQL_FIELD)+FieldOffsets.name)^, StrLen(PPAnsichar(NativeUInt(MYSQL_FIELD)+FieldOffsets.name)^));
Result.ColumnName := ValueToString(PPAnsichar(NativeUInt(MYSQL_FIELD)+NativeUInt(FieldOffsets.org_name))^, StrLen(PPAnsichar(NativeUInt(MYSQL_FIELD)+NativeUInt(FieldOffsets.org_name))^));
```

When name and org_name have identical values the first parameter in the call to ValueToString evaluates correctly for name but evaluates to only the first character of the correct string for org_name.

The record structures and extraction code are in production. I am assuming the problem is with the way I am writing the string pointers to the record. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

David

Comment: Wide string vs ANSI string, again

Comment: Beyond the encoding problem lies issues with lifetime. How do you guarantee that the strings to which your pointers refer outlive those references?

Comment: @David Thanks for your help. I spent some time on the string type suggestion but did not come up with a solution. However, a try at the lifetime question appeared to solve the problem. I'm willing to go with this. If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer I'd be happy to mark it as correct. My thanks either way.